# Why does this code get undefined but not 2?

Tags: javascript, scheme

I try to translate this Scheme code to Javascript:

```
(define (double f)
  (lambda (x) (f (f x))))
(define (inc x) (+ x 1))
((double inc) 0)
```

`((double inc) 0)` means `(inc (inc 0))`, so it returns 2.

This is my Javascript code:

```
var double = function(f){
    return function(x) { f(f(x)); }
}
var inc = function(x) {return x+1;}
double(inc)(0);
```

But `double(inc)(0)` returns undefined, not 2. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var double = function(f){
    return function(x) { return f(f(x)); }
}
var inc = function(x) {return x+1;}
double(inc)(0);
```

Small mistake :) should work with the return.

If a function doesnt return anything, it actually returns undefined.
In your double function you have a function which returns "nothing" => you get undefined.

Answer (score 7):

You missed `return` in `double` function:

```
    var double = function(f){
        return function(x) {return f(f(x)); }
    }
    var inc = function(x) {return x+1;}
    double(inc)(0);
```

Comment: This doesn't explain anything. It is just a game of spot-the-difference (or was before it was edited)

Comment: @ChaosPandion writing clear explanations is a better skill to have